# Conky (or other apps) on Gnome-screensaver unlock screen

Tags: 13.10, conky, gnome-screensaver

I found this awesome theme for conky to make it look like google now but it really gets in the way on my desktop. I want to put it on my unlock screen just like mint has a clock on the unlock screen. I found [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/239834/can-conky-be-visible-on-a-locked-screen#_=_) thread but it's old and unanswered. Any ideas?
BTW I'm running saucy

Comment: This is possible with xscreensaver, see http://askubuntu.com/a/545326/260842.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have put the following in /usr/lib/xscreensaver (in debian/CrunchBang) i use the name conkyslide for that file.

```
glslideshow -root -pan 0 -fade 3 -zoom 100 -titles -delay 10 &
killall conky &
conky -q &
```

remember to do "chmod +x" on the file.

a problem is "killall conky" that kills the desktop conky also

i am thinking of writing a script that reruns conky now and then to put it back on the desktop but has not yet done that.

a nother problem is that my conky does become transparent but black backgrounded.

You can read about a similiar solution and inspiration on: http://crunchbang.org/forums/viewtopic.php?id=4093

this puts the conky on the screensaver. But stays for me during onlock.