# How to get conky work even in lock screen?

Tags: lock-screen, conky

As the question goes, is there a way to get conky work even when is the system is locked?

Comment: You may try this http://vogelchr.blogspot.com.br/2012/11/ligthdm-custom-app-on-login-screen.html

Comment: See also http://askubuntu.com/questions/368829/conky-or-other-apps-on-gnome-screensaver-unlock-screen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is possible with [xscreensaver](http://www.jwz.org/xscreensaver/):

1) Install xscreensaver

```
sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-data
```

2) run "xscreenserver-demo" once in order to create an initial configuration file

```
xscreensaver-demo
```

3) Edit the configuration file *.xscreensaver* in your home directory

```
gedit ~/.xscreensaver
```

4) Append the following line to the list of programs (in my case, directly after the line containing `"unicode -root \n\"`)

```
"Conky"  conky -q --window-id=$XSCREENSAVER_WINDOW -c ~/.conkyrc-screensaver \n\
```

5) Put your conky config file under the name *.conkyrc-screensaver* in your home directory.

Here an example for a [sample conky config](http://pastebin.com/iBD8bHqj) file for displaying the cpu load:

```
wget http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=iBD8bHqj -O ~/.conkyrc-screensaver
```

6) Start the xscreensaver daemon and open settings in the opening window

```
xscreensaver &
```

7) Select "Conky" as screensaver

[image: Screenshot]

You can find more information on how to set xscreensaver as default screensaver in [Configure screensaver in Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292995/configure-screensaver-in-ubuntu).

Source: [How To: Conky as a Screensaver for xscreensaver](https://yalam.co.uk/blog/how-to-conky-as-a-screensaver-for-xscreensaver/)

Comment: can you please elaborate the 5th step please

Comment: Is it more comprehensible now? If not, can you tell me what exactly is unclear?

Comment: this works.. but I have one problem. When I lock the system with super+l then this does not work. Is there a fix even for that.

Comment: access to the source is denied. :https://yalam.co.uk/blog/how-to-conky-as-a-screensaver-for-xscreensaver/